# Inserir valores de um array de bytes em um array de int sem convertê-los

Tags: java, array, int, byte

Tenho esse vetor int:

```
int[] vetor = new int [dataRegCodeToCompare.length];
```

e esse vetor byte : (que recebe o "digest" de outro array de bytes)

```
byte[] dataRegCodeToCompare = md5.digest(toHash);
```

Quero colocar os valores do array de byte `dataRegCodeToCompare` no array int `vetor`. Mas, sem converter os valores; por exemplo em `dataRegCodeToCompare[0]=12` então quero que `vetor[0]=dataRegCodeToCompare[0]` que fica `vetor[0]=12`. Isso com todos os valores do `array`.

Não estou conseguindo simplesmente fazer `vetor = dataRegCodeToCompare`.

Comment: Se entendi bem faça `for(int i=0; i < dataRegCodeToCompare.length; i++){vetor[i] = dataRegCodeToCompare[i];}`

Comment: Isso mesmo @ramaral muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Até onde eu sei, não existe uma função pronta do Java que permita você fazer isso em uma linha, talvez por ser algo relativamente simples.

Por via das dúvidas, fui confirmar o que o [Jon Skeet falou sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6057546/1964435), e pelo menos em 2011 não existia.

Você pode implementar isso você mesmo assim:

```
public class ByteInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, (byte) 130}; //exemplo
        int[] sin = converteByteSinalizadoParaInt(bytes);
        int[] naoSin = converteByteNaoSinalizadoParaInt(bytes);

        System.out.println("Sinalizados");
        for(int s: sin) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("\nNão Sinalizados");
        for(int ns: naoSin) {
            System.out.println(ns);
        }
    }

    public static int[] converteByteSinalizadoParaInt(byte[] entrada) {
        int[] sin = new int[entrada.length];
        for(int i =0; i<entrada.length; i++) {
            sin[i] = entrada[i];                
        }
        return sin;
    }

    public static int[] converteByteNaoSinalizadoParaInt(byte[] entrada) {
        int[] naoSin = new int[entrada.length];
        for(int i =0; i<entrada.length; i++) {
            naoSin[i] = entrada[i] & 0xff;              
        }
        return naoSin;
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Sinalizados
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   -126
>
> Não Sinalizados
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   130